# Collision in hashmap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, collision

I have read about the Hashmap collision and took the following example. Since i am not able to understand what is collision and how to avoid collision is occurs. The example is follows

```
import java.util.*;  
class JavaCollision{  
public static void main(String args[]){  

 HashMap<Person, String> map=new HashMap<Person, String>();
 Person p1 = new Person(1,"ABC");
 Person p2 = new Person(2,"DEF");
 Person p3 = new Person(1,"XYZ");
 Person p4 = new Person(1,"PQR");
 Person p5 = new Person(1,"PQR");
 System.out.println("Adding Entries ...."); 
 map.put(p1,"ONE");
 map.put(p2,"TWO");
 map.put(p3,"THREE");
 map.put(p4,"FOUR");
 map.put(p5,"FIVE");

 System.out.println("\nComplete Map entries \n" + map);

/* System.out.println("\nAccessing non-collided key");  
 System.out.println("Value = "+map.get(p2));
 System.out.println("\nAccessing collided key");    
 System.out.println("Value = " + map.get(p1));*/
 System.out.println("P1 hashcode is:"+map.get(p1).hashCode()+" And value is:"+map.get(p1));
 System.out.println("P2 hashcode is:"+map.get(p2).hashCode()+" And value is:"+map.get(p2));
 System.out.println("P3 hashcode is:"+map.get(p3).hashCode()+" And value is:"+map.get(p3));
 System.out.println("P4 hashcode is:"+map.get(p4).hashCode()+" And value is:"+map.get(p4));
 System.out.println("P5 hashcode is:"+map.get(p5).hashCode()+" And value is:"+map.get(p5));
}
}
```

Person.java

```
public class Person {
private int id;
private String name;

public Person(int id, String name) { 
    this.id = id; this.name = name;
}

public String getName() { 
    return name;
}

public int getId() { 
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) { 
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName (String name) { 
    this.name = name; 
}

public int hashCode(){
    System.out.println("Called hashcode for:"+id+" - "+name);
    return id;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj){
    System.out.println("Called equals on ="+id+" - "+name+" to compare with "+((Person)obj));
    boolean result=false;
    if(obj instanceof Person){
        if( ((Person)obj).getId() == id  && ((Person)obj).getName().equals(name) ){
            result=true;
            System.out.println("Result is true");
        }
    }
    return result;
}
public String toString() { 
    return id+" . "+name;
} 
}
```

And the result is

```
Adding Entries ....
Called hashcode for:1 - ABC
Called hashcode for:2 - DEF
Called hashcode for:1 - XYZ
Called equals on =1 - XYZ to compare with 1 . ABC
Called hashcode for:1 - PQR
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . ABC
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . XYZ
Called hashcode for:1 - PQR
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . ABC
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . XYZ
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . PQR
Result is true

Complete Map entries 
{1 . ABC=ONE, 1 . XYZ=THREE, 1 . PQR=FIVE, 2 . DEF=TWO}
Called hashcode for:1 - ABC
Called hashcode for:1 - ABC
P1 hashcode is:78406 And value is:ONE
Called hashcode for:2 - DEF
Called hashcode for:2 - DEF
P2 hashcode is:83500 And value is:TWO
Called hashcode for:1 - XYZ
Called equals on =1 - XYZ to compare with 1 . ABC
Called hashcode for:1 - XYZ
Called equals on =1 - XYZ to compare with 1 . ABC
P3 hashcode is:79801726 And value is:THREE
Called hashcode for:1 - PQR
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . ABC
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . XYZ
Called hashcode for:1 - PQR
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . ABC
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . XYZ
P4 hashcode is:2158258 And value is:FIVE
Called hashcode for:1 - PQR
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . ABC
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . XYZ
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . PQR
Result is true
Called hashcode for:1 - PQR
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . ABC
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . XYZ
Called equals on =1 - PQR to compare with 1 . PQR
Result is true
P5 hashcode is:2158258 And value is:FIVE
```

In this result p4 and p5 having same hashcode. How to avoid the same hashcode using in hashmap. Can we able to avoid the collision by returning hashcode.

Comment: If you want to avoid collisions just don't hash the same key with a different value. Which is what you are doing for `p4` and `p5`.

Comment: Use some function that returns unique value to produce hashcode for your object.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So here p4 and p5 objects are collision right ?

Comment: @Muthuvigneshk Correct. Essentially `p5` is replacing `p4` here, which is why you see  `P4 hashcode is:2158258 And value is:FIVE` rather than `P4 hashcode is:2158258 And value is:FOUR`

Comment: Your code does not make sense: `System.out.println("P5 hashcode is:"+map.get(p5).hashCode()+" And value is:"+map.get(p5));` you are NOT showing hashcode of p5.  You are showing the hashcode of value associated with p5, which means you are showing `"FIVE".hashCode()` (which has nothing to do with HashMap logic).  To avoid collision, the only suggestion is to build a better `hashCode` function.  If your `equals()` have `name` involved in equality check, you should include `name` in the hashcode calculation.

Answer (score 3):

You have a weird understanding of what collision in a `HashMap` is. It is actually pretty simple - it's when two objects have the same hashcode **after** the internal re-hashing is done inside a `HashMap`:

```
static final int hash(Object key) {
    int h;
    return (key == null) ? 0 : (h = key.hashCode()) ^ (h >>> 16);
}
```

Basically after you compute the hashcode, `HashMap` will take the first 16 bits and `XOR` those with the last 16 bits - the ensure better distribution. If, after this re-hashing, two *different* keys have the hashcode value - this is called a hash collision. This means that two entries will end-up in the same bucket.

But generally this is ever a performance bottleneck, as entries that are placed in the same bucket (after they reach a certain number) are put into a `perfectly balanced red-black tree`, and the search is still very fast. For example if there are `2 pow 32` entries in this bucket, it will take **max** 32 steps to find this entry; the general search time being `O(logn)` in this `Tree bucket`. And for the map itself the search time would be `O(1)` - constant.

So don't complicate yourself - while you could test your `Key#hashCode` so that it has a *better* hashcode - don't do that, unless you are sure that there is a performance issue (which I highly doubt).

Answer (score 1):

> In this result p4 and p5 having same hashcode.

Correct, but that's not the issue here. The issue is that p4 and p5 have the same *key*, i.e. the value of `id`. A Map doesn't contain duplicates, so p4 was overwritten by p5, because they have the same `id`, not just the same hashcode.

> How to avoid the same hashcode using in hashmap.

There is no need to avoid collisions in HashMaps, and that isn't the problem here.

> Can we able to avoid the collision by returning hashcode.

Yes, but that's not the issue here. If you want both p4 and p5 in this map, you will have to give them different *keys.* What that means in this case is that as your `equals()` method is based on both `id` and `name`, so should your `hashCode()` method be:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    return id+name.hashCode(); // for example
}
```