# How to retrieve values after a hash collision

Tags: java, hashmap, new-operator, data-retrieval, hash-collision

I have read in many places that after a hash collision in Java it is internally using a linked list/tree, based on the number of hash collisions.Till this is fine,

But how to retrieve back the expected value using the 'key'

Comment: Assuming you're talking about a HashMap, using its `get()` method.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45952231/collision-in-hashmap/45955336#45955336)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just iterates the linked list stored in that bucket and checks the elements using `equals` which has no *collisions*.

The running time for that is linear, but only linear in the amount of items stored in that specific bucket, so it is okay as long as the buckets are kept balanaced well enough.

Look at this illustration ([source](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MJpDYFUhETI/VyTbS1HrsHI/AAAAAAAABA4/y3lqbDg0WUwouNFnDfGGr9-pJGxEF3wnACLcB/s1600/hashset-architecture.png)):

[image]

So the implementation will make sure that a `get` operation, even if it has collisions, gives back the correct result in the end.

---

Note that Javas `HashSet` and `HashMap` are not a pure hashtable like illustrated. They will switch to a [red-black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) internally after a certain threshold.

Comment: But we have only 'key' at the time of retrieval. So as per my knowledge how to check the equals method. I may be wrong

Comment: @JijoFrancis `keyFromUser.equals(keyInMap)` and if that is `true`, it will assume it is the correct key. The map/set does all of that internally. If you call `map.get(key)`, you will get back the correct value.

Comment: @JijoFrancis a collision is not two keys being equal. A collision is two keys that are not equal, but have a hashCode that leads to place them in the same bucket. In that case, when getting the value for one of those keys, the map checks if the first key is equal to the one passed by the user, then the second one, until the equal key is found.